# Erlang: one of two nodes is not ping in first time, after ping from second node, ping starts to work on both nodes

Tags: erlang, freebsd, ping

I have two machines: `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.2` on LAN. The first time the ping to first node is not working:

```
192.168.0.2> net_adm:ping('name@192.168.0.1').
pang
192.168.0.1> net_adm:ping('name@192.168.0.2').
pong
192.168.0.2> net_adm:ping('name@192.168.0.1').
pong
```

However, after I do the ping from `192.168.0.1` node to `192.168.0.2` node ping appears.
Tell me why is this happening?

> Without ipfw. All machines have "~/.erlang.cookie". FreeBSD 9.0
>
> Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]
>
> erlang-15.b.03.1,3
>
> Eshell V5.9.3.1

**I decided problem** and wrote the article http://adw0rd.com/2013/2/11/erlang-epmd-pang/en/

Comment: How did you start the erlang nodes?

Comment: `erl -name name@192.168.0.1 -setcookie TEST` && `erl -name name@192.168.0.2 -setcookie TEST`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a firewall issue. Host 192.168.0.1 may have blocked the connection request from 192.168.0.2.

Try disabling firewalls on 192.168.0.1, on Linux:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: I have FreeBSD 9.0 and disabled firewall "ipfw".

Comment: I decided problem and wrote the article http://adw0rd.com/2013/2/11/erlang-epmd-pang/en/